# form tag does not show

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Using asp.net mvccontrib grid. When using the custom column, the form tag isn't shown:

```
@(Html.Grid<SomeModelType>(Model.PagedList)
  .Columns(columns => 
  {
      columns.Custom(
          @<text>
               @using(Html.BeginForm("DeleteAction", "Controller", new { Id=@item.UserId}))
               {
                   <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
               }
           </text>
      );
  })
  .Sort(Model.GridSortOptions)
)
```

It outputs: `<input type="submit" value="Delete" />` in the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
@(Html
    .Grid<MyViewModel>(Model)
    .Columns(columns => 
    {
        columns.Custom(model => Html.Partial("_DeleteLink", model));
    })
    .Sort(Model.GridSortOptions)
)
```

and inside the `_DeleteLink.cshtml` partial:

```
@model SomeModelType
@using(Html.BeginForm("DeleteAction", "Controller", new { id = Model.UserId }))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
}
```

Comment: @Lol coder, I think the problem comes from the fact that the `BeginForm` helper doesn't directly write to the output and so doesn't work well with the MVCContrib `Custom` column. Also it seems that externalizing this markup into a partial would make your view code cleaner as you won't be mixing lots of markup with the MVCContrib Grid helper.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use `@<text> </text>`?